# Moralis cloned dapp throwing error (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, moralis

I was watching this "I Cloned OpenSea in 2 Hours" video on Youtube by the Moralis channel and decided to clone the final project (which started from the github repo of the ethereum boilerplate).

After cloning I ran npm install and installed the dependencies, changed the .env.example to .env and assigned my AppID and ServerURL values from Moralis. Now, when I run npm start I get this React error on my browser: "Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/link/crossorigin-error for more information.".

I tried Cleaning my local storage in Dev Tools from Chrome but nothing. What am I doing wrong? Here I leave the [github repo which I cloned](https://github.com/ethereum-boilerplate/ethereum-nft-marketplace-boilerplate)

Comment: That happens when the server isn't sending the right cors headers. There's not much you can do about it except ask them to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You may see this error if you haven't uploaded your contact's ABI. As I see from your steps above - you didn't do this. So, follow the quickstart

Comment: you mean my contract that mints the NFTs in the testnet?

Comment: btw its not only my NFTs that I minted, no collections from the rinkeby testnet appear here but any ethereum mainnet collection shows up

Answer (score -1):

Try this

0. if you dont have Chrome Developer Tools - install them
1. Open them
2. On top, nav bar, open application tab
3. Expand local storage, right click and clear

Comment: I already tried this but no luck